# Cabecera Accept-Encoding para SoapClient

Tags: php, soap

No hay manera de incluir una cabecera 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' a una petición SoapClient con SoapHeader y __setSoapHeaders. ¿Alguien me puede orientar?

```
$sc = new SoapClient($url1, array("trace" => true, "exceptions" => false)); 
$sh = new SoapHeader(/*xxxxx*/); // Aquí qué?
$sc->__setSoapHeaders($sh); 
$rs = $sc->__doRequest($xml, $url2, "http://www.blablabla", '1.2');
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

me respondo yo mismo.
Me equivocaba. Lo que quería no debía incluirse en cabeceras SoapHeader sinó en opción de constructor SoapClient.

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP));
```

Me obstiné con eso.